# Is Login with google / facebook / twitter authentication ? or authorisation?

Tags: facebook, authentication, authorization, single-sign-on, google-signin

I read about authentication & authorization. The blogs said SAML is authentication protocol & OAuth 2.O is Authorization framework .
Summarizing what I know about this .

1. Authentication is to get Username & Password and authenticates them once and allow them to access any integrated apps using SSO .
2. Authorization is providing Access token to the client application to access the application without providing password and other details to the client.

Doubt is Why Login with Google / Twitter / Facebook or other social login is not authentication ? because they use OAuth right .

Actual scenario confusing me is ,
Take app "monkey" which implements google / fb signin/signup .
I am new user  to their app. I choose google/fb signup option , as it is easy for me to access without creating new password.

How can they know am a authenticated user to use their app. Because google / fb gonna only authorise the app to use my details, not they authenticating me to their app right.

So every app which has social login function is authenticating me to use their app right.Then OAUTH can also use for authentication right ?

If I am wrong or misunderstood above mentioned terms & details , kindly clear me here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google, Facebook, Twitter use **OpenID Connect** that is an additional authentication layer over OAuth2.0.

So you can authenticate using OAuth2.0 using this additional layer.

Hope it answers your question.